# Let suspend function not return anything

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Consider this class:

```
class TestViewModel(private val interactor: LoginInteractor) : ViewModel() {

    private val _loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = false }
    val loading: LiveData<Boolean> = _loading

    fun loginClicked() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _loading.value = true
            val isLoggedIn = interactor.login()
            _loading.value = false
        }
    }

}

interface LoginInteractor {
    suspend fun login(): Boolean
}
```

and the test:

```
class TestViewModelTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var interactor: LoginInteractor
    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var tested: TestViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        Dispatchers.setMain(TestCoroutineDispatcher())
    }

    @Test
    fun `should set loading to true while loading`() = runBlockingTest {
        given(interactor.login()).willReturn(true)

        tested.loginClicked()

        Assert.assertTrue(tested.loading.value!!)
    }
}
```

When asserting that the value of `loading` is `true`, it actually isn't, obviously.

When we worked with RxJava, the `LoginInteractor` would have looked like:

```
interface LoginInteractor {
    fun login(): Single<Boolean>
}
```

and in the test, we could have done

```
given(interactor.login()).willReturn(Single.never())
```

to test the state of the ViewModel at the moment of logging in; how can I delay / not return anything of my interactor's `suspend` function `login()` to test the state of the ViewModel when `loginClicked()` is called, but `interactor.login()` has not returned yet?

Comment: You're mocking out suspendable functions. A framework that's aware of this should be the one to offer the option of the function never returning. However, even if this is achieved, you can't just run the assertion that the `loading` flag is raised. It can take any amount of time for the concurrent coroutine to reach that state. A correct test would use a time-based loop that retries the assertion until true or a timeout occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

To guarantee that your state is changed, you can subscribe to changes on loading state:

```
@Test
 fun `should set loading to true while loading`() = runBlockingTest {
     given(interactor.login()).willReturn(true)

     var invocationCounter = 0
     tested.loading.observerForever { loading -> 
         assertEquals(invocationCounter == 0, loading)
         invocationCounter++
     }

     tested.loginClicked()

     Assert.assertTrue(tested.loading.value!!)
 }
```

Option 2:

````
   ```
     given(interactor.login()).willAnswer {
         assertTrue(tested.loading.value)
         true
    }

    tested.loginClicked()

    Assert.assertFalse(tested.loading.value!!)
````

Comment: Which option have you chosen? :)

Comment: #2 for now, seems more intuitive.